# The @Rule > must be public ValidationError in Kotlin Junit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, kotlin

I tried to use a unit test rule annotation and Android Studio didn't highlight any error here:

```
@Rule val htmlManager = HtmlManager()
```

However after executing the test following error happens:

> org.junit.internal.runners.rules.ValidationError: The @Rule
>   'htmlManager' must be public.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The solution is to apply @Rule annotation to property getter:

```
@get:Rule
val htmlManager = HtmlManager()
```

more detail here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#java-annotations

see the fixed test case code here in my open-source project: https://github.com/appham/Sharemarks/commit/310c115d5a820be900abc321cc061aeab7af2e5a#diff-5e1e851ef5b9bb333abb96dec3199a94

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the `@JvmField` annotation

```
@Rule @JvmField 
val htmlManager = HtmlManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is:

```
val htmlManager = HtmlManager()
    @Rule get() = field
```